# returning multiple values in value returning function

Tags: c++, function, c++14

I want to write a program that counts the number of times a certain vowel appears in a string but each value must be returned.

```
int vowel_count(string);
int main()
{
  string str;
  cout << "Enter a string";
  cin >> str;
  // Calling funtion:
  vowel_count(str);
}

int vowel_count(string var)
{
  int sum_a = 0;
  int sum_e = 0;
  int sum_i = 0;
  int sum_o = 0;
  int sum_u = 0;
  
  for (int j = 0; j < var.length(); j++)
  {
        if (Var.at(j) == 'a')
            sum_a++;
        if (Var.at(j) == 'e')
            sum_e++;
        if (Var.at(j) == 'i')
            sum_i++;
        if (Var.at(j) == 'o')
            sum_o++;
        if (Var.at(j) == 'u')
            sum_u++;
  }
    return sum_a;
    return sum_e;
    return sum_i;
    return sum_o;
    return sum_u;
}
```

Everytime I return , the program terminates, I would like to know how to I overrun the function of return.

Comment: You can only return one thing from a function. But that thing can be as complex as you want. You can make your own struct with many members, or you can use a `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) to return multiple values from a function. Then you can either use [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) or [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) to get at the values in the tuple. This avoids having to define a struct/class simply for the purpose of returning a result from your function `vowel_count()`.

Since you tagged your question with C++14, I assume you haven't got C++17. However, with C++17 you can use [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to extract the values instead.

For C++11/C++14:

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<tuple>

using TupleVowel = std::tuple<int, int, int, int, int>;

TupleVowel vowel_count(std::string var)
{
    int sum_a = 0;
    int sum_e = 0;
    int sum_i = 0;
    int sum_o = 0;
    int sum_u = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < var.length(); j++)
    {
        if (var.at(j) == 'a')
            sum_a++;
        if (var.at(j) == 'e')
            sum_e++;
        if (var.at(j) == 'i')
            sum_i++;
        if (var.at(j) == 'o')
            sum_o++;
        if (var.at(j) == 'u')
            sum_u++;
    }

    return std::make_tuple(sum_a, sum_e, sum_i, sum_o, sum_u);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sum_a = 0;
    int sum_e = 0;
    int sum_i = 0;
    int sum_o = 0;
    int sum_u = 0;
 
    std::tie(sum_a, sum_e, sum_i, sum_o, sum_u) = vowel_count("hello world");
    std::cout << "sum_a = " << sum_a << ", sum_e = " << sum_e << ", sum_i = " << sum_i << ", sum_o = " << sum_o << ", sum_u = " << sum_u << std::endl;
}
```

Live [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vhceP7).

You can also use `std::get()` with the index of the element like this without having to 'tie' the tuple elements to variables:

```
auto tup = vowel_count("hello world");
std::cout << "sum_a = " << std::get<0>(tup) << ", sum_e = " << std::get<1>(tup) << ", sum_i = " << std::get<2>(tup) << ", sum_o = " << std::get<3>(tup) << ", sum_u = " << std::get<4>(tup) << std::endl;
```

In C++17, you can just do:

```
auto [sum_a, sum_e, sum_i, sum_o, sum_u] = vowel_count("hello world");
```

Live [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/51j6f5).

Answer (score 2):

When the type of the returned variable is the same, you can use a `std::array` (also `std::vector` or `std::deque`, but, given that the number of the returned variable is fixed, I suppose `std::array` is preferable)

I mean, something as follows

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

auto vowel_count (std::string var)
 {
   int sum_a = 0;
   int sum_e = 0;
   int sum_i = 0;
   int sum_o = 0;
   int sum_u = 0;
  
   for ( auto const & ch : var )
      if ( ch == 'a')      ++sum_a;
      else if ( ch == 'e') ++sum_e;
      else if ( ch == 'i') ++sum_i;
      else if ( ch == 'o') ++sum_o;
      else if ( ch == 'u') ++sum_u;

   return std::array<int, 5u>{ sum_a, sum_e, sum_i, sum_o, sum_u };
 }

int main()
{
   std::string str;
   std::cout << "Enter a string";
   std::cin >> str;

   auto vc = vowel_count(str);

   std::cout << "a: " << vc[0] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "e: " << vc[1] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "i: " << vc[2] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "o: " << vc[3] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "u: " << vc[4] << std::endl;
 }
```

Observe that, starting from C++17, you can use structured bindings, exactly as suggested from jignatius in the `std::tuple` based solution.

```
auto [sum_a, sum_e, sum_i, sum_o, sum_u] = vowel_count(str);

std::cout << "a: " << sum_a << std::endl;
std::cout << "e: " << sum_e << std::endl;
std::cout << "i: " << sum_i << std::endl;
std::cout << "o: " << sum_o << std::endl;
std::cout << "u: " << sum_u << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are way too complicated.
The easiest solution is a simple struct.

```
struct VowelResult {
    int a;
    int e;
    int i;
    int o;
    int u;
};
VowelResult func () {
    int sumA = 0;
    int sumE = 0;
    int sumI = 0;
    int sumO = 0;
    int sumU = 0;

    //your code goes here...

    return {sumA,sumE,sumI,sumO,sumU}; // order matters here
    // alternatively:
    // VowelResult res{};
    // res.a = sumA;
    // res.e = sumE;
    // and so on...
    // return res;
    // alternatively alternativey you can simply use the struct directly to store the sums
}
```